# how can I keep `<C-f>` literal in map definition?

Tags: key-bindings

I've write myself a function, which receive a motion and perform it in other window. However, a problem raises when I need to map a real motion to a key sequence:

```
nnoremap <c-p> :call Motion('\<C-F>')<cr>
```

Unexpectedly, `vim` executes `<C-F>` for me when I just want `vim` to put `<C-F>` there as string literal.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: use double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a literal `Ctrl+f` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in insert mode, but I'm not sure this will work for you.

The other method which I find more correct (or easier and more widely used) is to pass the key/motion as a string and use `:execute` to create the maps inside your function. Here is an example from the [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/plugin/ctrlp.vim#L38-L40) plugin:

The part in the plugin:

```
if g:ctrlp_map != '' && !hasmapto('<plug>(ctrlp)')
        exe 'map' g:ctrlp_map '<plug>(ctrlp)'
en
```

You can set the motion in .vimrc as:

```
let g:ctrlp_map = '<C-f>'
```

and then `<plug>(ctrlp)` would be mapped to it.

In your case you would have a simple call in .vimrc like this:

```
nnoremap <c-p> :call Motion('<C-F>')<cr>
```

and in `Motion`:

```
function Motion(sequence)
    " other stuff
    execute 'map' a:sequence '<Plug>(action)'
    " more stuff
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to replace the `<` in `<C-f>` with `<lt>`

```
nnoremap <c-p> :call Motion("\<lt>C-F>")<cr>
```

This will prevent `:map` from interpreting `\<C-f>` as a special mapping, but it does send a literal `<` to the `Motion()` function.

Also note you need to use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Aside: I just spent half an hour figuring out why my mapping doesn't work. Vim can be such a pain sometimes 